# $_{1}{{F}_{1}}\left( 1,c,(a+b)x \right)-\, _{1}{{F}_{1}}\left( 1,c,ax \right)=(?)$

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am looking for:
$$_{1}{{F}_{1}}\left( 1,c,(a+b)x \right)-\, _{1}{{F}_{1}}\left( 1,c,ax \right)=(?)$$

where $x$ is between $0$ and $T$ and $a,b,c>0$.

I know the asymptotic behavior as $x$ goes to $\infty$, but at this situation that will not help me.

I also know the following relation, but not sure how to use it. 
$$\frac{\partial _{1}{{F}_{1}}\left( 1,c,x \right)}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{c}\, _{1}{{F}_{1}}\left( 2,c+1,x \right)$$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is no explicit expression in terms of elementary functions. One can only write the result via incomplete gamma functions.

Comment: That would be great. Can you tell what would it be in terms of incomplete gamma function. Thanks so much!

Comment: $_1F_1(1,c,x)=(c-1)e^x x^{1-c}\left(\Gamma(c-1)-\Gamma(c-1,x)\right)$